# Mass email to contacts, using visualforce email template

Tags: apex, pardot

I have a Visualforce Email Template, I am trying to send out emails to Multiple contacts with related Leads data. I am unable to include visualforce template in the mass email. 
Leads: fields sample1__c, sample2__c, sample3__c(this is a lookup to contact)
Contact: Name , Email

Challenge is I **have** use Pardot to achieve this.

Can I send mass emails to contacts with related leads data in Pardot, if I convert my visualforce email to HTML email?

Answer (score 0):

If each email is going to be unique, your code will need to basically prepare the HTML for each Pardot Prospect to be emailed out, then use Pardot's Send One-to-One email API to send the prepared HTML and TEXT content.

You might be able to get away with having Pardot Prospect Custom Fields to store the information, though this falls apart if you are going to include multiple "records" of information in your email template.  If your email has relatively "flat" data that will be included, you could prepare an HTML/TEXT template with HML tags for placing the right data in the right place, and use the Pardot Send List email API by specifying the HTML and Static/Dynamic list.

It's not going to be super easy, though it should be possible.